# Unable to connect from PHP Azure to SQL Server Azure using PHP with Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, azure, odbc

I am trying to connect from a php app (using codeigniter 3) to a MSSQL database.

As the Azure PHP installation does not support MSSQL, only ODBC connections (I wonder why) my connection parameter look like this: (hostname, username, database and passwords in this sample overridden with xxxxx,ddddd,uuuuu,ppppp)

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => @$_SERVER['SQLAZURECONNSTR_ddddd'],
    'hostname' => 'Driver={SQL Server};tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ddddd',
    'username' => 'uuuuuu',
    'password' => 'pppppp',
    'database' => 'ddddd',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Message: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data > source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in > SQLConnect
>
> Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php

I would have assumed that the azure php odbc driver would be correctly configured to connect to its linked mssql database. - But I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure environment doesn't install **`php_mssql.dll`** extension, it installs **`php_sqlsrv.dll`** instead.

So to connect to SQL Server, we can set **`'dbdriver'`** to **`'sqlsrv'`**.

The setting in application\config\database.php should be like:

```
'hostname' => '<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433',
'username' => '<username>',
'password' => '<password>',
'database' => '<database>',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
```

As  to use `odbc` driver to connect to SQL Server, we just need to set `'hostname'` to a correct `odbc` connection string. We can find the connection string in Azure portal.

I tried to reproduce your issue,
it seems that you set an incorrect value in `'dsn'`. In my test, I set it as an empty string and it works for me.

Comment: Is there anything else you need to do, for instance configure the firewall settings for the SQL Server? I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL Server from an Azure Web App and just keep getting "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." with CodeIgniter, I've tripled checked the hostname/username/password etc. What else could it be?

Comment: Ignore me, I changed the password just to be on the safe side and now it seems to be working - don't need any IP addresses set in the firewall settings.

Comment: @xceed, congratulations. And by the way, if you are testing on local, the operation is required.